# Searching unique web links

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the program to extract the web links from http://www.stevens.edu/.
Now i am facing following problems with the program.

1- i want to get only links starting from http and https

2 - I am getting a parser warning from bs4 concerning the lack of specification on a parser - solved

How can fix this problems? I am not getting proper direction to solve this problem.

my code is -

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = raw_input('Please enter the url for which you want to see unique web links -')

print "\n"

URLs (mostly HTTP) in a complex world
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs(html)
tags = soup('a')
count = 0
web_link = []
for tag in tags:
    count = count + 1
    store = tag.get('href', None)
    web_link.append(store)
 print "Total no. of extracted web links are",count,"\n"
 print web_link
 print "\n"
 Unique_list = set(web_link)
 Unique_list = list(Unique_list)

 print "No. of the Unique web links after using set method", len(Unique_list),"\n"
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, your definitions of "web links" and "local content" seem rather ambiguous. Did you mean you're looking for html files and not css or do you mean you're looking for unique domains? Or something else?

Comment: for warning you can have soup = bs(html,"lxml"). For the getting only web link you can have a condition like if 'http' in tag.get('href', None):

Comment: `if 'http' in tag.get('href', None):` will still get stylesheets or anything by that matter served over http though.

Answer (score 0):

for second problem, you need to specify the parser while creating a bs of the page.

`soup = bs(html,"html.parser")`

This should remove your warning.